# Smarty: print a specific element of an array WITHOUT using foreach loop

Tags: php, smarty

```
{foreach from=$myArray item=item}
    {$item.attribute}
{/foreach}
```

instead of printing all attributes of each element of the array, I want to output only the 3rd element WITHOUT using a foreach loop, is it possible?

I'm looking for something like the below, but I don't know the syntax:

```
$myArray[2].attribute
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`{$myArray[2].attribute}` would be correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{$myArray.2.attribute}` to get the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

$myArray[2]->attribute   this one works for me.